# Строку в "float"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Этот скрипт преобразует float десятичного числа в двоичное с плавающей точкой. Как реализовать скрипт, который будет делать это в обратном порядке, из строки двоичного кода обратно в десятичное число float?

```
def float_bin(number, places = 3): 

    # split() seperates whole number and decimal  
    # part and stores it in two seperate variables 
    whole, dec = str(number).split(".") 

    # Convert both whole number and decimal   
    # part from string type to integer type 
    whole = int(whole) 
    dec = int (dec) 

    # Convert the whole number part to it's 
    # respective binary form and remove the 
    # "0b" from it. 
    res = bin(whole).lstrip("0b") + "."

    # Iterate the number of times, we want 
    # the number of decimal places to be 
    for x in range(places): 

        # Multiply the decimal value by 2  
        # and seperate the whole number part 
        # and decimal part 
        whole, dec = str((decimal_converter(dec)) * 2).split(".") 

        # Convert the decimal part 
        # to integer again 
        dec = int(dec) 

        # Keep adding the integer parts  
        # receive to the result variable 
        res += whole 

    return res 

# Function converts the value passed as 
# parameter to it's decimal representation 
def decimal_converter(num):  
    while num > 1: 
        num /= 10
    return num 

# Driver Code 

# Take the user input for  
# the floating point number 
n = input("Enter your floating point value : \n") 

# Take user input for the number of 
# decimal places user want result as 
p = int(input("Enter the number of decimal places of the result : \n")) 

print(float_bin(n, places = p))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться преобразованием в число с помощью функции [int](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), но указать что планируете использовать двоичную систему:

```
def bin_float(number):
    base, fraction = number.split(".")
    return float(f"{int(base, 2)}.{int(fraction, 2)}")


print(bin_float("10001.10"))
```

По сути задача сводится к тому как каждую двоичную часть преобразовать обратно в целое число, а потом объединить в строку с разделяющей точкой и скормить это функции float.

Кстати, возможно посмотрев на предложенный код вы упоростите изначальную функцию в своем вопросе, она сильно усложнена.